# How to import Javascript file into angular's shadow dom

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, shadow-dom

I have an Angular web component (angular-elements) and I'm trying to include bootstrap.js and jquery to my component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'catalago-component',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
```

I've tried the following:

angular.json

```
    "scripts": [
      "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
    ]
```

list.component.html

```
  <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

list.component.ts

```
import 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js';
import 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';
```

none of them worked but if remove `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` then it works fine. So how can I import those js files without removing `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`

Comment: as I know you can't redefine styles, that's one of main web-component ideas

Comment: Instead of trying to get jQuery based Bootstrap to work, you could instead use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) or similar, Bootstrap implementations intended to be used with Angular.